# Special scroll-bar design can it be made in all browsers?

Tags: html, css

Is this scroll-bar possible to make in all browsers ? it doesn't have arrows and scroll is in a different shape.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible but it requires some javascript (it's not available in css)

Try to use for example this plugin (it requires jQuery): http://jscrollpane.kelvinluck.com/